reimaging win11 arm64 stuck at Starting Bootmgr
reimaging new arm64 hardware. Snapdragon X chip, surface laptop 7. I built a bootable with rufus4.5 (from exfat, NTFS is the only option in rufus), the win11 pro iso i need to use, booting with secure boot disabled, and PID in the directory. The process times out at "Launching aa64 efi" and "Starting Bootmgr" see the pic below.
Starting Microsoft Windows bootmgr... stuck
I have played with the boot config to allow it to go for longer but it times out at 60 seconds regardless of what I enter.

Where did you get the ISO? I wasn’t aware Rufus could download Windows on ARM. Why are you not using the recovery image provided by Microsoft?

From a microsoft enterprise portal I'd assume. My security-first manager pulled it for me, just provided me the iso. Its a surface laptop with a snapdragon x chip, it shipped to me with Home and we use Pro. If rufus can't build this, what can? Ive never used anything differently but also only ever used x64 arch.

You need to better understand the source of the ISO. Why are you not using the recovery image provided by Microsoft?

Do I install the Home version from the recovery tool and then can update it to Pro with a generic key? I'm unfamiliar with this

You can't update to Professional from Home since you won't be able to activate it. If you have a license for Professional, you should install the recovery image and then do an in-place upgrade with the Processional license you do have.

Is it at all possible to flash the pro image from a usb?

Recovery products for all Surface devices are hidden away a device serial authentication wall, technically speaking, just using a Windows on ARM ISO should have worked.  However, ARM is a different architecture than x86_64, and your problem does indeed seem to be connected to the image you're attempting to use. You might be able to modify the Windows image on the recovery image, with DISM to include Windows 11 Professional.
